# How to Filter Data from an API call by Category and Display it in the UI?

Tags: angular, search, ionic4

I’m trying to retrieve the data by category, by **generation** to be specific from a Pokemon API and retrieve all the pokemon species into the generation it falls as selected in the option list but I’m having some hard time to do so. I can already get the array of pokemon species in the console log but I can't implement it in my view. Anyone who can help me with this. Thank you!

Here's the method I used for fetching species by generation:

```
  getPokeGenerationSpecies(id) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/generation/7`).pipe(
      map((poke) => {
        let id = Object.keys(poke["id"]);
        poke["id"] = id.map((idKey) => poke["id"][idKey]).filter((id) => id);
        return poke;
      })
    );
  }
```

As you can notice above, I only hardcoded the index value to 7 but what I really want is to get it dynamically as I select a generation number.

This is what I log in the console:

[image]

Here, I would like to access all the list of pokemon_species and display all of it in my view.

This is the interface I'm trying to achieve dynamically:

[image]

But I only hardcoded the data here:

```
  <h4>POKÉDEX</h4>
  <ion-card-subtitle> Search by generation. </ion-card-subtitle>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select</ion-label>
    <ion-select (ionChange)="onChange($event)">
      <ion-select-option [value]="1">Generation 1</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option [value]="2">Generation 2</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option [value]="3">Generation 3</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option [value]="4">Generation 4</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option [value]="5">Generation 5</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option [value]="6">Generation 6</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option [value]="7">Generation 7</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
  <!-- <ion-list-header>Generation {{""}}</ion-list-header>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>... list of species of selected generation here</ion-item>
  </ion-list> -->
</div>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <h5>Generation 1</h5>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label><b>Charmander</b></ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label><b>Pikachu</b></ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label><b>Bulbazour</b></ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label><b>Pichu</b></ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label><b>Salamander</b></ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label><b>Meow</b></ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
```

Here's my onChange method:

```
 onChange(event) {
    let value = event.detail.value;
    console.log(event.detail.value);
    if (value == "") {
      this.offset = 0;
      this.loadPokemon();
      return;
    }

    this.pokeService.findPokemonByGeneration(value).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.pokemon = [res];
      },
      (err) => {
        this.pokemon = [];
      }
    );
  }
```

And here's my findPokemonByGeneration method:

```
  findPokemonByGeneration(search) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/generation/${search}`).pipe(
      map((generation) => {
        generation["generationIndex"] = generation["id"];
        return generation;
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why cannot directly use the array filter function

```
return poke.filter((item) => {
  return  item.id === id;
});
```

Or create a generic pipe to filter any property, see the link it may help you:

[Filter and Sorting in Angular](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1211/angular-2-search-and-sort-with-ngfor-repeater-with-example)